# Broken micro usb solder pads on pi 3 B+

Tags: pi-3b+

I have picked up these for 6.5 dollars each. Top one is in decent condition i can solder some usb ports and use it but the below one has some issues with micro usb port. Solder pads and traces are ripped of. I know i can use the solder pads under the pcb but i want to use some kind of usb port with that. Upgrade to type c is an option. All small pads except gnd is gone and the bigger pads are also gone. I could not find a pcb layout of this model. I want to try removing some soldermask and solder some tiny wires to the board. I want them only be on top layer. Where should i solder them. I don want to use gpio pins since they dont have any protection.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]